# Xcode 5 crashing when trying to validate archives

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, crash, app-store

I had a couple questions when trying to put an app on the app store.

1) With Xcode 5 when trying to validate the archived project, Xcode 5 keeps crashing when trying to download the provisioning profile from the net. I have refreshed the provisioning profiles using the Preferences >> Accounts >> View Details and have clicked the refresh button but it still crashes when I try to validate.

2) Is it best practice to have a separate distribution certificates and provisioning profiles for each app you put on the app store? right now I have a separate provision profile for my apps but they are under one certificate. Can you guys tell me what the best practice is?

3) And can you try to explain what the certificates and the provision profiles are doing? Also, what would the difference between distribution provision profiles and development provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) - Check what version of Xcode you're running. I had a similar issue where I was running a developer preview - you can't submit an app from a DP version of Xcode, and mine was crashing at the exact same point as yours.

2) - Having 2 certificates - 1 for dev, 1 for distribution seems to be the norm. I would suggest that you use explicit app ids and not the wildcard ID when you go to create your App ID though.

3) The way I see it, Provisioning profiles are your wrappers for your different things that make it up - mainly the signing certificate, the app id and the device id(s) - You select either a distribution or a dev signing certificate to determine if the app is being developed or submitted to the app store. You select the App ID to tell the app what functions it will have (iCloud, Data protection, etc) and what teams can work on the app. The Devices are what UDIDs are authorised to run this app that has this associated provisioning profile. The provisioning profile is how it's all packaged up.

As another way to look at it, You have your .ipa file (your app) and your provisioning profile. The device looks at the profile, checks if the devices UDID is present in the provisioning profile, checks the App ID to see what features it's allowed to run, and the certificate is used to sign it all off.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like I'm using Version 5.0 from the Xcode >> About Xcode. I'm not running the DP version of Xcode. I was able to send in one app already so I don't think it's the versioning. Thanks for the information on the profiles and certificates it helped me understand it a little more.

Comment: If you throw up the console files from when Xcode is crashing I'll tell you what's going on. The ones from the console.app, not the xcode console =]

Comment: can you please tell me how to access them?